# How to select shifted time periods in MDX?

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

I am beginner in MDX. I am trying to calculate the increase in revenue from the previous year using the Adventure Works cube in a way that I will have a column that will show the difference in revenue between 2 years. Until now I was able to calculate the difference manually using:

```
(KpiValue("Revenue"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2009]) - KpiValue("Revenue"), 
[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008] 

(KpiValue("Revenue"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]) - KpiValue("Revenue"), 
[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2007] 

(KpiValue("Revenue"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2007]) - KpiValue("Revenue"), 
[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2006]
```

Can you suggest me more efficient way to calculate this. I think I can use the Parallel Processing function but I am struggling to understand how it works.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is the code I use:

```
with member [diff] as
(KPIValue("Revenue"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]) -
(KPIValue("Revenue"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2007])

Select
{diff} on 0
FROM [Adventure works]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **PrevMember**:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[Diff] as
[Measures].[Revenue] - ([Date].[Fiscal Year].PrevMember,[Measures].[Revenue])

Select 
[Measures].[Diff] on 0,
[Date].[Fiscal Year].[Year].Members on 1
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a CURRENTMEMBER somewhere?

Comment: Nope, am I? [Date].[Fiscal Year].CurrentMember is automatically piked by  OLAP engines if it's not specified.

Comment: @DanyloKorostil Explicit is better than Implicit. In many situations the OLAP engine *does not* automatically use CURRENTMEMBER but uses the ALL member

Comment: It depends on a query. Usually the algorithm is: CurrentMember ->  DefaultMember -> AllMember. But it doesn't mean that .CurrentMember is .[All].